# ejb remote method works locally but give error remotely

Tags: java

i created an `ejb` remote interface, deployed it on my local machine on `glassfish` application server and it worked perfectly, but while testing it on a remote server it deployed successfully but i could not access the remote method when validation a login form, giving the following error:

> javax.ejb.EJBException
>
> at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5215)
>
> at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5113)
>
> at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
>
> at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
>
> at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
>
> at 
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandl
>   er.java:222)
>
> at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocat
>   ionHandlerDelegate.java:89) at
>   $Proxy206.findStudentByFirstName(Unknown Source)
>
> at pac.Serve.processRequest(Serve.java:46) at
>   pac.Serve.doPost(Serve.java:124)
>
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
>
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
>
> at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>
> at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>
> at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>
> at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>
> at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>
> at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>
> at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>
> at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>
> at 
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>
> at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>
> at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>
> at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>
> at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>
> at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>
> at 
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>
> at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>
> at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>
> at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>
> at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>
> at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>
> at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>
> at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>
> at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: Exception
>   [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse  Persistence Services -
>   2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   'schooldb.Jss_Student_Details' doesn't exist Error Code: 1146 Call:
>   SELECT firstName, lastName FROM schooldb.Jss_Student_Details WHERE
>   (email = ?) bind => [1 parameter bound] Query:
>   ReportQuery(name="JssStudentDetails.findByEmail1"
>   referenceClass=JssStudentDetails sql="SELECT firstName, lastName FROM
>   schooldb.Jss_Student_Details WHERE (email = ?)")
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:644)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1717)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:566)
>
> at 
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:264)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:646)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2611)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllReportQueryRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2554)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ReportQuery.java:846)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1040)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:392)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1128)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:485)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getResultList(EJBQueryImpl.java:742)
>
> at wak.capableDoa.findStudentByFirstName(capableDoa.java:34)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>
> at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>
> at 
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
>
> at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
>
> at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
>
> at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
>
> at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>   at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
>
> at
>   org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:42)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>
> at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>
> at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
>
> at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>   at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
>
> at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
>
> at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>
> at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>
> at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
>
> at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>
> at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
>
> at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
>
> at 
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
>   ... 30 more Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   'schooldb.Jss_Student_Details' doesn't exist
>
> at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
>
> at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
>
> at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
>
> at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
>
> at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3283)
>
> at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1332)
>
> at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1467)
>
> at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.PreparedStatementWrapper40.executeQuery(PreparedStatementWrapper40.java:642)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:931)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:607)
>   ... 81 more

please can some one help with a solution to this error, 
thanks in advance.

Comment: If you look at the exception, you are getting an SQL error. I think one of two is happening; either you changed something in the configuration that causes the SQL error (easy to check if you test again the server EJB) or you are executing not the EJB stub but the EJB itself in the client...

Comment: Where is that exception is being throw? Post the full code.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with remote/local ejbs... it's an SQL error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'schooldb.Jss_Student_Details'     doesn't exist
```

Comment: ive tried storing information to the database and it worked perfectly, but trying to validate a login form and retrieve from a table in the database give the above error

Comment: here is my validate code that couldnt work remotely but worked perfectly locally

Comment: public class Serve extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    private capableDoaRemote capableDoa;

Comment: protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String Fname = request.getParameter("usrnam");
        Integer Pass = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("pass")).intValue();

Comment: try {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            List<Object[]> Ins = capableDoa.findStudentByFirstName(Fname);
            List<Object[]> pas = capableDoa.findStudentByStudPin(Pass);
            List<Object[]> cas = capableDoa.findStudentByFirsttName(Fname);
            List<Object[]> tas = capableDoa.findStudentByStudePin(Pass);
            if(!Ins.isEmpty() && !pas.isEmpty()){
                for(Object [] xx : Ins){
                session.setAttribute("usrnam", xx[0]);
                session.setAttribute("usrn", xx[1]);}

Comment: request.getRequestDispatcher("Student_sessionsss.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }
            else{
            request.setAttribute("check", "Incorrect username or pin, please try again or contact the school Admin thank you!");
             request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }   
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
             request.setAttribute("error", ex);
             request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }

Comment: @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

Comment: @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

Comment: @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }

Comment: please help me go through the codes and see if they are correctly placed thank you in advance